# How do I send a MIDI message with a MIDITimestamp to AKMIDISampler?

Tags: ios, audiokit

I am trying to integrate AudioKit to my sequencer app.

Currently trying to figure out how to send a MIDI message with a MIDITimestamp value to a AKMIDISampler instance. In the interface of this class there are no methods that allows to specify a timestamp value for the note commands.

I don't use AKSequencer. I want to schedule commands from my own sequencer.

Is there any help for my case from the AudioKit, or should I write the scheduling code myself?

Answer (score -1):

@dimitry,

If you're attempting to play `AKMIDISampler` instance variables from your non-`AKSequencer`, I believe you just need to trigger them; it is your sequencer that sends the MIDI event at a given timestamp, and just informs the AKMIDISampler to play at that moment in the sequence.

For instance:

```
 func playKick() {
    try! kick1Sampler.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127, channel: 0)
 }
```

Without seeing your sequencer implementation or project, are you able to send MIDI events from your sequencer? If so, you can add the `AKMIDIListener` delegate and capture the received MIDI note events from your sequencer like this:

```
func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID? = nil, offset: MIDITimeStamp = 0) {
    outputMIDIMessage = "Channel: \(channel+1) noteOn: \(noteNumber) velocity: \(noteVelocity))"
    print(outputMIDIMessage)
}

func receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID? = nil, offset: MIDITimeStamp = 0) {
    outputMIDIMessage = "Channel: \(channel+1) noteOff: \(noteNumber) velocity: \(noteVelocity))"
    print(outputMIDIMessage)
}
```

Please note that I am using AudioKit version `4.9.2` and Xcode 11.2.1.

Comment: It is not very possible to send an event at a given timestamp. To make it accurate you need to do it from the audio thread and provide sampleOffset values. I know how to implement it myself (already did, in fact). I just was asking maybe there is already some code  in the AudioKit lib, so I can just use it. Seems like there is not.